# Phonegap localstorage and object-oriented JS

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, sqlite, local-storage

I have the following method:

```
DBConnection.prototype.successHandler = function(){
  console.log("DB_INFO: Schema created");
  for (k in this) console.log(k);
  this.setStatus(DB_STATUS_OK);
}
```

I call this in a transaction like this:

```
DBConnection.prototype.createSchema = function(){
  try {
    this.c2db.transaction(
      function(tx){
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person(id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT "");',
        [], this.nullDataHandler, this.errorHandler);
        tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO person(id, name) VALUES (NULL, 'miloud');",
          [], this.nullDataHandler, this.errorHandler);
      },
      this.errorHandler,
      this.successHandler
    );
  } catch(e){
    console.log("DB_ERROR: error during insert with message: " + e);
    return;
  }
}
```

The problem is that I get: **Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'setStatus'**  which is clearly telling that what I am accessing is not the `DBConnection` instance that I am using when I am in the success callback. How come? What is this refering to inside this callback? Is there a way to overcome this problem?

EDIT

Callbacks are defined as:

```
DBConnection.prototype.errorHandler = function(errorMsg){
  console.log("DB_ERROR: error creating schema with msg " + errorMsg.message);
}
DBConnection.prototype.successHandler = function(){
  console.log("DB_INFO: Schema created");
  for (k in this) console.log(k);
  this.setStatus(DB_STATUS_OK);
}
```

And setStatus method as

```
DBConnection.prototype.setStatus = function(str_status){
  localStorage.setItem(db_name, str_status);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs because `this` within a javascript function refers to the object that preceded it in a dot notation when called. But functions in javascript are first-class values and can be called outside of objects (or indeed, for totally different objects). For example, if `obj` is an object:

```
obj.myFunc = function() { console.log(this) };
obj.myFunc(); // <- Here this === obj
var freeFunc = obj.myFunc; // The function is just a value, we can pass it around
freeFunc(); // <- Now this === the top object (normally window)
            // Still the same function, but *how* it was called matters
```

What you are doing is passing the function referred to by `this.successHandler` into the `transaction` call, but the function doesn't know anything about the object you took it from. When it is called by `transaction` it is executed without an object and `this` just becomes `window`.

To solve this you can use the fact that javascript has closures and wrap the function with another anonymous function:

```
DBConnection.prototype.createSchema = function(){
  try {

    var that = this;

    this.c2db.transaction(
      function(tx){
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person(id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT "");',
        [], this.nullDataHandler, this.errorHandler);
        tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO person(id, name) VALUES (NULL, 'miloud');",
          [], this.nullDataHandler, this.errorHandler);
      },
      this.errorHandler,
      function() { that.successHandler(); }
    );
  } catch(e){
    console.log("DB_ERROR: error during insert with message: " + e);
    return;
  }
}
```

Now `successHandler` will be called with `that` as `this`, which is the same as the original `this`.

This is a common misconception about `this` but there are also lots of explanations online, just google "javascript this".